# No network connection and error

Tags: windows, internet, networking

My PC keeps reporting the following error in the event viewer around every 10-15 minutes: `Faulting application , version 0.0.0.0, faulting module unknown,
version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x00000000.`  Whenever it happens, the XP theme change to classic theme then change back to the normal theme. The network goes down and I must restart PC for the network to come back online.  What could be causing this and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the extremely not-useful error message (another favourite of mine is *"The data is the error"*), sometimes the standard link that is shown for each event, in fact links to a very specific knowledge base article. You can get there by clicking the blue link in Event Viewer:

> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp

(which, *when clicking from the Event Viewer*, might include the event ID if applicable).

So, not very likely, but: maybe Microsoft surprises you if you click it. :-)

(See also [How To Solve Any Windows Problem with Event ID](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-solve-your-windows-problems-with-event-id/).)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an executable starts every 10-15 min that does these funny stuff and aborts.

If the idea of examining the Event Log doesn't work out, you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) : Leave it running and when the funny stuff starts, immediately switch to Process Explorer - the ending process will be highlighted in red for 1 second. You can prolong the delay to more than 1 second by using the menu Options / Difference highlight duration.

Comment: Process monitor might be better because it'll log the process startup so you don't have to catch it running.